# What technology does Milo.com use for it's 'Locate Me' feature?

Tags: location

How does this work? Please provide a detailed answer on how to build this feature from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Look into HTML5 Geolocation. See this:
http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation/

As per that code, you want to use navigator.geolocation to retrieve the appropriate position:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) 
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 

        function (position) {  

        // Did we get the position correctly?
        // alert (position.coords.latitude);

        // To see everything available in the position.coords array:
        // for (key in position.coords) {alert(key)}

        mapServiceProvider(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

        }, 
        // next function is the error callback
        function (error)
        {
            switch(error.code) 
            {
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    alert ('Timeout');
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    alert ('Position unavailable');
                    break;
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    alert ('Permission denied');
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    alert ('Unknown error');
                    break;
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
else // finish the error checking if the client is not compliant with the spec
```